# Return Item into for loop after exception in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, for-loop

```
que = []
def worker(x):
    for idx, Item in enumerate(range(1, 3)):
        try:
            #Do Stuff
            print("Fin", Item, "For Worker", x)
        except Item > 2:
            que.append(Item)
            pass


worker(1)
worker(2)
```

My problem is that I dont know how to tell the for function to do the try part also for items in `que` when there are some. So It would see that `Item 3` in open in que, switch to `worker 2` and try from there again.

Current output looks like:

```
Fin 1 For Worker 1
Fin 2 For Worker 1
Fin 1 For Worker 2
Fin 2 For Worker 2
```

Expected output should look like:

```
Fin 1 For Worker 1
Fin 2 For Worker 1
Fin 3 For Worker 2
```

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do. could you explain it a little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you might want something like this, this goes over the range AND the que in the for loop

```
que = []

def worker(x):
    for Item in range(1, 3).extend(que):
        try:
            #Do Stuff
            print("Fin", Item, "For Worker", x)
        except Item > 2:
            que.append(Item)
            pass


worker(1)
worker(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You told your second worker to do the exact same thing as the first one. Instead, you need a second function which iterates over `que`.

```
def worker_repeat(x):
    for Item in que:
        try:
            #Do Stuff
            print("Fin", Item, "For Worker", x)
        except:
            print("Failed again", Item, "For Worker", x)
            pass
```

Please note that you are relying on `que` being a global variable here, which is usually bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit unclear but maybe you were trying to do something like this:

```
def worker(x, que):
    # do tasks in the queue
    for task in que.copy():
        try:
            if task == 3 and x == 1:
                raise ValueError  # worker 1 fails when doing task 3
            print("Fin", task, "For Worker", x)
            que.remove(task)  # task was successful - remove it from queue
        except ValueError:
            pass  # if task was not successful - leave it on queue


que = [1, 2, 3]  # set up a queue of tasks to be done
worker(1, que)  # process items on the queue
worker(2, que)  # process whatever still remains on the queue
```

Gives output:

```
Fin 1 For Worker 1
Fin 2 For Worker 1
Fin 3 For Worker 2
```